# How to move a character to another column in the same row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got stuck trying to clean a dataframe similar to this one:

| code | course name | EOS | Mid | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA101 | Course 1 | 350 | 420 | NaN |
| AA102 | Course 2 | 400 | 470 | NaN |
| AB101 | Course 3 | #560 | 570 | NaN |
| AB102 | Course 4 | 410 | 465 | NaN |
| AC101 | Course 5 | # | 522 | NaN |

I need to keep only numerical values in the column `EOS` and move `#` characters that appear in it to the column `test`, to indicate that an additional test is required for that course. This is because some of the values have a `#` before the actual number, such as `Course 3`, and some have only the `#` as the value, such as `Course 5`.

The dataframe was created using Camelot to extract those values from a PDF table.

What I need is to take this `#` out of this column and add it to the `test` column instead.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    [  ["AA101", "Course 1", "350",  420,   None],
       ["AA102", "Course 2", "400",  470,   None],
       ["AB101", "Course 3", "#560", 570,   None],
       ["AB102", "Course 4", "410",  465,   None],
       ["AC101", "Course 5", "#",    522,   None]  ],
    columns = ["code", "course name", "EOS", "Mid", "test"]
)

transformed_data = (
    data
    .assign(test=lambda d: d["EOS"].apply(lambda d_: "#" if "#" in d_ else None))
    .assign(EOS=lambda d: d["EOS"].replace({"#": ""}, regex=True))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin function to do just this, but it can be done using two lines:

```
df.loc[df['EOS'].str.contains('#', na=False) 'test'] = '#'
df['EOS'] = df['EOS'].str.replace('#', '')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    code  course name  EOS  Mid test
0  AA101     Course 1  350  420  NaN
1  AA102     Course 2  400  470  NaN
2  AB101     Course 3  560  570    #
3  AB102     Course 4  410  465  NaN
4  AC101     Course 5       522
```